# Join Table Active Record Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have a join table `lab_tests` which stores a list of tests that a particular lab has with the schema of `lab_id` and `test_id`.

I want to get a list of labs that have all tests that are passed into the params.

I currently have the following scope -

```
scope :test_filter, lambda {|test_id|
    return nil if test_id.blank?
    where(:test_id => test_id)
}
```

But this gives me a list of labs with at least one test. How can I get a list of labs with contain all the tests in the given params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the trick using GROUP BY and HAVING. If you filter your association table for all the wanted `test_id`s and group it by `lab_id`, then if the number of grouped records is the same as the number of tests, you are certain that the lab includes all these tests (it may include some other tests though but I guess you don't mind that).

So, try something like this:

```
# Lab model:
scope :with_tests, -> (test_ids) {
  return Lab.none if test_ids.blank?

  joins(:lab_tests).
    where(lab_tests: { test_id: test_ids }).
    group(:lab_id).
    having("count(*) = ?", test_ids.count)
}
```

Notes:

- The scope returns a [`none` scope](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/none) in case of empty `test_ids`. This is a better approach then returning `nil` because `none` is a normal chainable scope that can be used in the same way as other scopes (chaining `nil` would throw an exception).
- You have not specified where your scope resides so I thought the Lab model might be a good place - this way the scope returns the Labs with *at least the given* tests.
- The scope joins in the association table and filters only those records with the `test_ids`. `test_ids` should be an array of test IDs wanted in the lab. The condition will be run as an `IN` clause in the `WHERE` condition of the SQL.
- Then it uses the grouping trick - it groups by `lab_id` and returns only those records which have the same count of tests in the group as the number of input tests. I.e. it returns only **those labs which have at least all the given tests.**